# data get from firebase in initstate not working, flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently writting a code to fetch a firebase data in initState.
But no matter what I do it does't return or does't store data so I get following error.
I'm getting error at code  *Text(userName["username"].toString())*

> Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The
> method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> )

Please teach me how to make it work.
Since I'm using setState inside of by code I would not like to use futurebuilder nor streambuilder to perform it.

```
  class _reviewWriteHomeState extends State<reviewWriteHome> {
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var userName;
  String? userIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future(() async {
      fetchData();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    });
  }

  Future fetchData() async {
    final userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc("user").get();
    final pos = (userSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    setState(() {
      userName = pos;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Text(userName["username"].toString()),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const newPage()));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `future` in `initState()` is not a best idea, you can use `addPostFrameCallback` inside `initState`, or use it before returning widget tree to the `build` method
and you don't really have to use the future builder.

here is an example

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      Future(() {
      fetchData();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    });
    });
```

or You can use `FutureBuilder`. refer [BouncyBits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75671195/16613306) answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use `future` in `initState` instead use the `FutureBuilder`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // Future(() async { // Remove these
     // fetchData();
     // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    // });
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc("user").get(), // Call your future function directly here
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          return Text(data['username']); 
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

Update:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc("user").get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        name = value.data()?['username'];
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child:
              name != null ? Text(name!) : const CircularProgressIndicator())

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'm aware that futurebuilder are manage to perform it but since I have so much setState in actual use case (code posted are simplyfied for post) I would like to avoid using futurebuilder or streambuilder since every setstate re-render a build and that cost one extra read for Firebase.

Comment: You can see my updated answer @AkiraYoshimura

Answer (score 0):

You declared `userName` as:

```
var userName;
```

Since you don't specify a default value, that means that its initial value is `null`. Since you only set the vale of `userName` when you get data from Firestore (many seconds later), the UI will be rendered while `userName` is still `null`. And in the `build` method you then do:

```
Text(userName["username"].toString())
```

Since `username` is `null` initially, you're trying to call `["username"]` on it, which isn't valid. And that's exactly what the error message tells you.

A simple way to solve this is to show a loading indicator while the user name is being loaded:

```
userName != null? Text(userName["username"].toString()) : const CircularProgressIndicator()
```